# Maui Android compile / first screen ok > first action fails

Tags: android, visual-studio, maui

compiling my .net Maui app with Android 13.0 API 33: first screen comes up correctly . But first 'Button' action fails!
i.e. nothing comes up except a 'circle' turns for a very short time (no error msg).
ALL ok when compiling with 'Windows Machine', AND, I have other Apps which work with Android 13.

You can check the App in GIT: https://github.com/edikaufmann/HikeGIT.

I'm in the learning phase of Maui - what do I possibly need to check/correct?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that you have put the `RefreshView` inside of `VerticalStackLayout`.

There is a known issue about this, you can check it here: [[regression/7.0] [MAUI] RefreshView C1 details page loading was missing](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16492).

But as a workaround, you can put the `RefreshView` inside of `Grid`.

You can refer to the following code:

```
<Grid>
    <RefreshView Grid.Column="1"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="10"
                 Command="{Binding VARhCommand}"
                 IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}">

        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Hikes}" SelectionMode="None">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="{OnPlatform Android=1, Default=1}" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>


                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Hike">

                    <Frame WidthRequest="400">

                        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:HikesViewModel}}, Path=GoToDetailsCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>


                        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="Auto, *">
                            <Image Grid.Column="0"
                                   Aspect="Fill"
                                   HeightRequest="60"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                   Source="{Binding Image}" />
                            <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Column="1"
                                                 HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                                 WidthRequest="250">
                                <Label Padding="10"
                                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                                       Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                <Label Padding="10"
                                       FontSize="10"
                                       Text="{Binding Distance, StringFormat='{0} km'}" />
                            </VerticalStackLayout>
                        </Grid>


                    </Frame>

                </DataTemplate>

            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </RefreshView>

    <VerticalStackLayout WidthRequest="220">
        <Button x:Name="button1"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="3"
                Margin="8"
                Command="{Binding VARhCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{x:Reference button1}"
                IsEnabled="{Binding IsNotBusy}"
                Style="{StaticResource ButtonOutline}"
                Text="VAR-Haute" />


        <Button x:Name="button2"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="3"
                Margin="8"
                Command="{Binding GdVCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{x:Reference button2}"
                IsEnabled="{Binding IsNotBusy}"
                Style="{StaticResource ButtonOutline}"
                Text="Gorges du Verdon" />

        <Button x:Name="button3"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="3"
                Margin="8"
                Command="{Binding AdHPCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{x:Reference button3}"
                IsEnabled="{Binding IsNotBusy}"
                Style="{StaticResource ButtonOutline}"
                Text="Alpes de Haute Provence" />

        <!--  Add this  -->
        <Button Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="9"
                Margin="8"
                Command="{Binding GetClosestHikeCommand}"
                IsEnabled="{Binding IsNotBusy}"
                Style="{StaticResource ButtonOutline}"
                Text="Find Closest" />


    </VerticalStackLayout>

    <ActivityIndicator Grid.RowSpan="2"
                       Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"
                       IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"
                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
</Grid>
```